# VSFTPD set up in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to set an FTP server in a VM (CentOS 7). There are no firewalld or iptables services running. I have installed vstpd service and enabled it. Below are the enabled properties in vsftpd.conf

- anonymous_enable=YES
- local_enable=YES
- write_enable=YES
- local_umask=022
- dirmessage_enable=YES
- xferlog_enable=YES
- connect_from_port_20=YES
- chroot_local_user=YES
- allow_writeable_chroot=YES
- listen_ipv6=YES
- pam_service_name=vsftpd
- userlist_enable=YES
- tcp_wrappers=YES
- pasv_enable=YES
- pasv_max_port=6000
- pasv_min_port=6000

```
   [root@L00096a ~]# sestatus
   SELinux status:                 enabled
   SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
   SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
```

SELinux is enabled. Here are the sebools. I have turned ON ftpd_full_access

```
[root@L00096a ~]# getsebool -a | grep ftp
ftpd_anon_write --> off
ftpd_connect_all_unreserved --> off
ftpd_connect_db --> off
ftpd_full_access --> on
ftpd_use_cifs --> off
ftpd_use_fusefs --> off
ftpd_use_nfs --> off
ftpd_use_passive_mode --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
tftp_anon_write --> off
tftp_home_dir --> on
```

```
[root@L00096a ~]# netstat -lt
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ftp                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

The VM has sshd service running and I use root credentials. I tried hitting the ip in the browser `ftp://<ip>` expecting it to show the ftp page but it did not. When I try from filezilla client, I see 421 service not available error.

I am not a linux expert, just trying to set up an FTP server to test my code. Could anyone please tell me what I should be checking next? Does it look like port 21 is enabled? Please guide.

Comment: Side note since you say you tried in the browser as well: writing this in fall 2021, it is not safe to assume web browsers speak the FTP protocol anymore.

Comment: This is just to test my code. Everything will be reverted. I just followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0aX5mPQCxM) where I could see just having the service running was enough to open up the ftp folder in the browser. Unfortunately did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> and I use root credentials

`vsftpd` by default doesn't allow to log in under root - that's 100% insecure as the password is sent in plain text over the net.

To enable root user in `vsftpd`, remove `root` from `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers` and `/etc/vsftpd/user_list` and restart it (`systemctl restart vsftpd`).

I've now verified it all works:

- I've installed `vsftpd` in CentOS 7 in default configuration (haven't changed a thing) in VirtualBox
- SeLinux is left on by default as well (`enforcing`),
- I ran `firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=ftp` followed by `firewall-cmd –-reload` to allow it through the firewall.

I can FTP in using root from my host PC to my virtual PC.

The error you see could be due to your FTP client whatever it is. Midnight Commander and plain old `ftp` both work here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did comment out root in user_list and ftpuser files and restarted the service. Still getting 421 error. Anything to do with the enabling port? I am able to ping from my windows but not do ftp <ip>, which throws 421. Kindly please guide.

Comment: I've no idea, error 421 could be caused by a lot of things. Please check `journalctl -u vsftpd` Try disabling SeLinux altogether. It doesn't make any sense to you anyways considering you're enabling such dangerous features.

Comment: I reverted all the "dangerous" changes. [Source](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-setup-ftp-server-install-vsftpd-centos-7) is what I followed in setting this up. There is no firewalld running.  Chrome network console tells the connection is stalled - meaning it could be because of more than 6 TCP connections or disk space... how can I further debug? Is disabling selinux the only way?

Comment: `vsftpd` by default tries to drop as many permissions as possible, so I'm not entirely sure you can connect to it using the root account anyways. Also, nothing prevents you from disabling SeLinux, testing it, and reenabling it.

Comment: ok I had added another "testuser" for this purpose and reverted the previous changes. I will try to disable selinux to check if that's what causing the problem. Let me get me back on this. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hello Artem, Tried disabling selinux and restarted the VM. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: Here's a CentOS 7 VirtualBox image which works: https://mega.nz/file/a8knDSbC#6SZGLwYCHaDk89CHbwv_Q9bWHGbmuZ2RG9YsmHnV0Fk It's 100% default aside from 2 modified vsftpd files. Root password is digits from 1 to 9 followed by 0.

Comment: Artem, I really appreciate your time & effort. I will try to use the image in my personal laptop to test. But I'm setting it up in my office laptop. I've followed same steps except firewall-cmd commands as firewalld is not running in the server. But no luck so far.

Comment: Worked. Used filezilla client. Just to point out for the noobs like me, I had to use "sftp user@<p>" instead of "ftp <ip>" while connecting from windows cmd. Also had to use the default sftp port 22. Thank you Artem for your guidance.